# Tailwindcss flex with min basis?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a layout with 2 panes. The right pane should not overlap the first pane when resizing, for responsiveness.

I'm trying to achieve this using Tailwindcss with a flexbox layout.

I would appreciate some guidance on this, please.

Please see the [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zd3gV0qbp9) - As you can see, I don't want the red div (right pane) to overlap the first when resizing.

Comment: So you want both panel to resize ?

Comment: The left panel is already resizing which is fine. I want the right panel to respect and not overlap with the left panel @ymt

Answer (score 0):

I added class `flex` and `min-h-screen` to the parent of both child divs to specify you have a flex layout and also set a fill height on all screens. Then went further to set `flex-1` on the gradient container, asking it to use any available space between both child components. This structure kind of makes both children adjust their width and prevent the overlap you were experiencing.

Maybe this is what you're trying to do. I hope :)

```
<div class="flex min-h-screen">
  <!-- Left Pane -->
  <div class="relative flex-1 overflow-hidden px-6 lg:pointer-events-none lg:fixed lg:inset-0 lg:z-40 lg:flex lg:px-0">
    <div class="absolute inset-0 -z-10 overflow-hidden bg-gray-950 lg:right-[calc(max(2rem,50%-38rem)+40rem)] lg:min-w-[32rem]">
      <svg class="absolute -bottom-48 left-[-40%] h-[80rem] w-[180%] lg:-right-40 lg:bottom-auto lg:left-auto lg:top-[-40%] lg:h-[180%] lg:w-[80rem]" aria-hidden="true">
        <defs>
          <radialGradient id=":R1d6:-desktop" cx="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(248, 56, 187, 0.3)"></stop>
            <stop offset="53.95%" stop-color="rgba(255, 0, 187, 0.09)"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(10, 14, 23, 0)"></stop>
          </radialGradient>
          <radialGradient id=":R1d6:-mobile" cy="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(248, 56, 187, 0.3)"></stop>
            <stop offset="53.95%" stop-color="rgba(255, 0, 187, 0.09)"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(10, 14, 23, 0)"></stop>
          </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#:R1d6:-desktop)" class="hidden lg:block"></rect>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#:R1d6:-mobile)" class="lg:hidden"></rect>
      </svg>
      <div class="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 right-0 h-px bg-black mix-blend-overlay lg:left-auto lg:top-0 lg:h-auto lg:w-px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Right pane  -->
    <div class="relative flex-auto">
      <div class="absolute right-0 h-56 w-full rounded-full bg-red-800 lg:w-[calc(max(2rem,50%-38rem)+40rem)] lg:max-w-[calc(max(42rem,50%-32rem)+40rem)] xl:w-[calc(max(2rem,50%-38rem)+40rem)] xl:max-w-none"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lesTjcUQ8k)